# ProductName length cause connection problem

Tags: iphone, connection, product

It seems incredible but if I put a productName (not BundleNamethat appears in home screen) longer than 10 chars my app works well except from I'm not able to get response of my connection requets.

I mean...for example if I put APPNAME123 in productName I obtain APPNAME123.app and all works fine.
If i put APPNAME1234 in productName  I obtain APPNAME1234.app and app works except for connections methods...for example if I call www.mydomain.com/example.asp I got no errors, but zero bytes as response!!!!

I use

```
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:MYURL];
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

and result is not nil but with zero length while error is nil

Of course I tried in various way (both on simulator and device), cleaning and rebuilding project avery time, and of course I tried with other names...same results..if longer than 10 chars I got same problems!
I've also created a new project with desired name longer than 10 chars and I got the same problem.

That made me crazy for a whole day...because I didn't find a specification for this and the rest of app wiorking good!!!
I'd like to know:

1) if anyone else notice this or itis just my problem, maybe some dirty on my mac
2) if there some documentation about this everywhere

thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that doesn't sound like your problem, sounds totally unrelated, perhaps remove products from simulator and do a clean and build. My guess is that you have 2 copies, one working and one broken on the simulator, and it is launching the wrong one.

Comment: I lost part of a day to that same thing... I eventually just put an assert(0) in the main call to see that I wasn't seeing my changes, because I wasn't executing the new code.

Comment: I don't think is my problem because I see every change I do, and also if I rename in various way the productName (i.e. APP, APP1, APP2, APP3) always cleaning and rebuilding the project...it always works...when i rename using more than 10 chars it stop to work...but just for connection response. And I've also tried to make a totally NEW project...getting same problem

Comment: I made a test that works just fine, you can download it from http://objectivelybetter.com/tests/LongAppName1234567890.zip

Comment: Grady finally I can say you were (partially) right. It's a very strange issue. Now i can say that the problem, obnly on my mac, is a combination of appName and url called in the request.

In fact I made a totally new project with long name (different than wich caused the problem but longer than 10 chars), write few code line to make a request...response were fine.

Then I re-made (after cleared also "DerivedData" folder) a new project with the name I wish to give to my app, write the same few code line to make a request...response were wrong. (Made me crazy)

Comment: Ok, then I changed the url of my site with another site...Response where fine!!! 

So, now I really thing that in my tool there something dirty involved appName and url of my site, but I don't know what.

Now I'm looking for a way to totally clean XCode, maybe changing the DerivedData folder...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a memory issue. What's about response, do you read it immediately? What if appname has a length of 12, 13, ... characters, any change than? Have you tried to have a look into memory browser before/after calling sendSyncRequest?

Comment: it is not about response because is a synchronous request so when the method exit the response is available!

Comment: in addition if I put more than 10 chars...11, 12, 13 and so on, I got the same problem

Comment: Strange. I have got some Apps on my iPhone containing more than 10 chars that performs http requests and they appear to request data synchronously. Do you have the same behaviour when using another URL?

Comment: Actually I didn't try it with another url...i'll do it